# Wobbly table - maybe an easy fix

Tags: technique, wood, design, wood-movement, stability

recently I've asked a woodworking professional to build me a table for my living room.

[image]

It looks good but the problem is: it is wobbly. I can pull and push it on the direction indicated below:

[image: Wobbly table]

I want to guarantee that he fixes the problem so that's why I would appreciate your professional help: if he builds these "triangular structures", does it fix the problem?

[image: Triagular structures]

Would the problem really be fixed? Is there an better solution?

Sorry for using so many tags, i didn't know how to "label" the question.

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to be sure from the perspective. In your "movement" picture, is the movement toward the tall black chair in the background, or is it toward the white chairs set at the desk? BTW - it is a very nice looking table!

Comment: @FreeMan hello! It is toward the tall black chairs. Thank you for the compliment! Best Regards.

Comment: Your professional woodworker needs to go back to the classroom to bone up on how to make rigid joints! He should have known ahead of time those small metal fixings were not at all sufficient here, not had to find out from the table itself.

Comment: Is it possible that he thought the table would be securely fixed on the wall?

Comment: @MaximeMorin no, he knew it wouldn't actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on a wobble going toward the black chair, then yes, the triangular braces between the table top and the legs will resolve the wobble.

Smaller braces would be better from a design perspective, but if they're too small, they won't be sufficient to stop the wobble.

It's difficult to tell, but it looks like there are small metal fasteners holding the legs to the table top, and they look like they've got 1" - 1 1/2" "legs". It might be sufficient to beef those up (maybe double the length of each leg?) to give the table the stability it needs, instead of putting a large wooden wedge under there.

Instead of experimenting on your nice looking table, your "woodworking professional" may want to knock together a quick mock-up in cheap (low-grade, scrap) plywood to see how small he can make the bracing while still having it be sufficient to do the job.

Comment: those are great advices and I thank you for that. Best Regards.